# How to apply a hover function to a Vue / Vuetify Autocomplete autocomplete list?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, autocomplete, hover, vuetify.js

I am more of a Vue-Noob, and find it to be a bit complicated to understand. Maybe you fellas see that code, and have the "best practice" or most compact solution for my problem:

I have an autocomplete dropdown box. On expand, i see a list with clickable entries. I would need to get the information of the hovered item, if the mouse hovers over the list.
Like, the method "doFunnyStuff" would push the data of the hovered object on hovering to a method, and do something with it (maybe externally or so)

Thank you in advance for any helpful comment!

```
<template>
  <v-autocomplete
    v-model="selected"
    dense
    outlined
    hide-details
    return-object
    background-color="white"
    light
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    hide-no-data
    style="width: 500px"
    :loading="loading"
    :search-input.sync="query"
    :items="items"
    clearable
  >
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ item }" return-object>
      <v-list-item @mouseenter="doFunnyStuff(item)">
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title> {{ item.text }}} </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </template></v-autocomplete
  >
</template>
    </template>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a tooltip component to display the data? Because vuetify has such a component. If it is just push the data to a method, you can declare makeFunnyStuff(item) in your methods and use the data however you want

Comment: No, not a tooltip, I use the data to do something completely different with it (i highlight something live on a geographic map application e.g.)
But, the method exists, it does not work. I think the v-list-item has no mouseenter event...

Comment: Got it. v-list-item has click and keydown events. If it is mousehover what you are looking for you could wrap your component in a div and use it. Let me know if this works for you =)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but when you want to do something with hovered item of expanded list, you should use **item** slot instead of **selection**.

**Selection** slot is used just for your selected item on top of the component, so your code works, but only when you hover your already selected item.

**Mouseenter** event is not related for any component in vuetify, it's an JS event that may be appended to any component (if was not appended before by vuetify or any different library, ofc).

So your code may be like:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-autocomplete
      v-model="value"
      :items="items"
      dense
      filled
      label="Filled"
    >
      <template #item="{ item, on, attrs }">
        <v-list-item @mouseenter="doFunnyStuff(item)" v-on="on" v-bind="attrs">
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title> {{ item }} </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </template>
    </v-autocomplete>
    <div>
      <p>{{ hoveredItem }}</p>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
    value: null,
    hoveredItem: "not hovered yet"
  }),
  methods: {
    doFunnyStuff (item) {
      this.hoveredItem = item;
    }
  }
})
```

[Codepen link with an example](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/WNOLMNB)